# Binarize bad background image using openCV Python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, opencv

I've tried to binarize passport images for OCR using following steps :

```
img = cv2.medianBlur(nid_aligned_image,3)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

this methods works well for better background image but not given type of images.

[image]

Here is the output and OCR can't read this

[image]

Can anyone suggest me a better approch ?

Answer (score 1):

My approach for the problem is:

---

**1-** Apply adaptive thresholding

**2-** Apply Morphological Transformation

**3-** Apply bitwise operation

Step 1: **Adaptive Threshold**

---

- From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

  - > if an image has different lighting conditions in different areas. In that case, adaptive thresholding can help. Here, the algorithm determines the threshold for a pixel based on a small region around it. So we get different thresholds for different regions of the same image which gives better results for images with varying illumination.
  - To summarize: when a global value used as a threshold is not performing well, you will use adaptive thresholding.
  - ```py
    img2 = cv2.imread("BESFs.png")
    gry2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    flt = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry2,
                                 100, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 16)
    ```
  - Result:

    - [image]

Step 2: **Morphological Transformation**

---

- From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html):

  - > It needs two inputs, one is our original image, second one is   called structuring element or kernel which decides the nature of operation
- We need to define a kernel (filter) for processing image.

  - ```py
    krn = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    ```
- We will use `opening` and `closing`:

  - > Opening is just another name of erosion followed by dilation. It is useful in removing noise
  - > Closing is reverse of Opening, Dilation followed by Erosion. It is useful in closing small holes inside the foreground objects, or small black points on the object.
- ```py
  opn = cv2.morphologyEx(flt, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, krn)
  cls = cv2.morphologyEx(opn, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, krn)
  ```

Step 3: **Bitwise Operation**

---

- From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

  - > They will be highly useful while extracting any part of the image
  - ```py
    gry2 = cv2.bitwise_or(gry2, cls)
    ```
  - Result:

    - [image]
- Now if we use `pytesseract` for extracting the text

  - ```py
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry2)
    txt = txt.rstrip().split('\n\n')[1].split(' ')[1]
    print("Passport number: {}".format(txt))
    ```
  - Result:

    - ```py
      Passport number: BC0874168
      ```

**Optional**

---

For your future OCR problem, you can try to enhance the image resolution. For instance:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("BESFs.png")
h, w = img.size
fct = min(1, int(1024.0/h))
sz = int(fct * h), int(fct * w)
im_rsz = img.resize(sz, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im_rsz.save("out_dpi_300.png", dpi=(300, 300))
```

For this problem it has no effect, but maybe it may help you in the future.

Code for the problem:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

img2 = cv2.imread("BESFs.png")
gry2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

flt = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry2,
                            100, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 16)
krn = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
opn = cv2.morphologyEx(flt, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, krn)
cls = cv2.morphologyEx(opn, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, krn)
gry2 = cv2.bitwise_or(gry2, cls)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry2)
txt = txt.rstrip().split('\n\n')[1].split(' ')[1]
print("Passport number: {}".format(txt))
```

Comment: I applied your approach. It didn't cover all but I used it as alternative method for OCR. BTW thanks for you answer

Comment: What do you mean by that? The only missing parts are "Republic of Bangladesh" and 30. Did you try with other images?

Comment: cover all means other images. but it works much better than before

Comment: Did you try again by removing the following sentence `txt = txt.rstrip().split('\n\n)[1]..`? Maybe it may work better for other images

Comment: I see, well thats the best I could do, using only one sample image